# Negative margin not working in phone view

Tags: css, web-frontend

I am trying to achieve a partially hidden object by shifting the object out of the screen.

I have tried using negative margin, relative position and using top and right properties, and also translate function.

The problem is it is working perfectly fine on browsers, but when I view it in phone simulation the shifting of x-axis disappears and instead the size of object is reduced. The part I want hidden(out of the screen view) comes into the view but this is happening only on x-axis.

[image: View in browser]

[image: View on phone simulation]

As it can be seen the object is still partially hidden in from above, but it comes out from the right side.

Here is my code:

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 10px;
}

.circles {
  float: right;
}

.circle {
  background-image: linear-gradient(30deg, rgb(0, 0, 0), rgb(30, 30, 30), rgb(60, 60, 60));
  position: relative;
}

#big-circle {
  height: 40vw;
  width: 40vw;
  border-radius: 20vw;
  transform: translate(4vw, -8vw);
}

#small-circle-1 {
  width: 3vw;
  height: 3vw;
  border-radius: 1.5vw;
  bottom: 30vw;
}

#small-circle-2 {
  width: 2vw;
  height: 2vw;
  border-radius: 1vw;
  bottom: 9vw;
  left: 30vw;
}
```

```html
<div class="circles">
  <div class="circle" id="big-circle"></div>
  <div class="circle" id="small-circle-1"></div>
  <div class="circle" id="small-circle-2"></div>
  <div class=""></div>
</div>
```

Comment: could you please add your html code?

Comment: @AlirezaSabahi I added the HTML code

Comment: It works correctly i think

Comment: @AlirezaSabahi I shared the screenshots, as you can see the circle is coming out from the right side in phone view but I want it partially hidden on the right as it is on desktop. Please refer to images.

Comment: @SamarpitShrivastava as you can see there is a scrollbar in your browserview, too. Take a look at my answer, may fix your problem.

Comment: @AlirezaSabahi I got the problem, I got rid of the scrollbar by using overflow:hidden property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is, that your circle gets scrollable.

You could solve your issue using `oveflow: hidden;` in your `.circle`-class like i did below:

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 10px;
}

.circles {
  float: right;
  overflow: hidden;    //    <- this will fix it. :)
}

.circle {
  background-image: linear-gradient(30deg, rgb(0, 0, 0), rgb(30, 30, 30), rgb(60, 60, 60));
  position: relative;
}

#big-circle {
  height: 40vw;
  width: 40vw;
  border-radius: 20vw;
  transform: translate(4vw, -8vw);
}

#small-circle-1 {
  width: 3vw;
  height: 3vw;
  border-radius: 1.5vw;
  bottom: 30vw;
}

#small-circle-2 {
  width: 2vw;
  height: 2vw;
  border-radius: 1vw;
  bottom: 9vw;
  left: 30vw;
}
```

```html
<div class="circles">
  <div class="circle" id="big-circle"></div>
  <div class="circle" id="small-circle-1"></div>
  <div class="circle" id="small-circle-2"></div>
  <div class=""></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'am not gonna lie, I just figured it out by myself and came here to update it and I saw your answer and you told the same thing. Anyways thanks a lot. But should I add the property overflow: hidden to a particular class or to the whole body tag?